# Convert T-SQL INNER JOIN on a Function to PL-SQL

Tags: oracle, t-sql, plsql

I have a `T-SQL` view that does this:

```
LEFT JOIN fnc_AssetAttributeByType(3) tmp
ON
A.AssetID = tmp.AssetID;
```

Is there a straight forward way I can translate this (I'm writing a tool to do it programmatically) without creating a `package` or modifying the header of the function that would void other calls to it in other DML statements?

**Main questions:**
1. Can I even write a PL function that returns a table?
2. If not, what should I do?

Comment: After reading it a couple of times, I *think* I know what you mean, but maybe you can elaborate a bit (especially on the 'Why' and 'End goal' part), so we know in which direction we may seek possible solutions or workarounds.

Comment: @GolezTrol Sure. Basically we have a product that uses SQL Server and we're adding Oracle support. Now, I know that I can probably go get the query in the T-SQL function and manually convert, an put it in the view to be equivalent to what's happening in T-SQL. I would much rather modify the function though so we can keep using that.

Comment: So, your answer is basically: YES you can :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that returns a table type, and work on it in SQL by using it inside a table() clause. The user running the SQL needs execute privilege on the function.

```
SQL> create or replace type tp_asset as object (assetId number, asset_name varchar2(100), asset_val number)
  2  /
Type created
SQL> create or replace type tp_tab_asset is table of tp_asset;
  2  /
Type created
SQL> create or replace function fnc_AssetAttributeByType(p_num in number) return tp_tab_asset pipelined as
  2    v_tp_asset tp_asset;
  3  begin
  4    for i in 1 .. 3
  5      loop
  6      v_tp_asset := tp_asset(i, 'ABC', i * 3);
  7      pipe row (v_tp_asset);
  8    end loop;
  9    return;
 10  end;
 11  /
Function created
SQL> select *
  2    from table(fnc_AssetAttributeByType(3)) a
  3    left join table(fnc_AssetAttributeByType(3)) b on b.assetid = a.assetid;
   ASSETID ASSET_NAME       ASSET_VAL    ASSETID ASSET_NAME       ASSET_VAL
---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ----------
         1 ABC                      3          1 ABC                      3
         2 ABC                      6          2 ABC                      6
         3 ABC                      9          3 ABC                      9
```

Comment: Can I do it without the stupid types? What should I have to know the column types?

Comment: In PL/SQL (not SQL) type can be specified as `tableName.columnName%TYPE`. SO if the `assetID` is being source from `assets.assetId`, you can (probably) use `assetId assets.assetId%TYPE` More typing, but you don't need to know the types, and any change in table types will be reflected automatically. I _think_ object is a PL/SQL thing so this way of specifying types will work.